# Pivot, CONCAT, one table and INNER JOIN with another table to create single table

Tags: sql, pivot

Im having hard time in creating mysql table in which i want to pivot one table and concat its columns after pivoting and then INNER JOIN it with another table to create single table.

SELECT
data_id,
Max(case
when name = 'ApplicantsFirstName' then value else '' end ) as ApplicantsFirstName,

Max(case
when name = 'ApplicantsMiddleName' then value else '' end ) as ApplicantsMiddleName,

Max(case
when name = 'ApplicantsLastName' then value else '' end) as ApplicantsLastName,

Max(case
when name = 'FathersFirstName' then value else '' end) as FathersFirstName,

Max(case
when name = 'FathersLastName' then value else '' end ) as FathersLastName,

Max(case
when name = 'Gender' then value else '' end ) as Sex,

Max(case
when name = 'checkbox' then value else '' end ) as Approval,

Max(case
when name = 'url' then value else '' end ) as url,

Max(case
when name = 'text' then value else '' end ) as Information

FROM wphl_cf7_data_entry
GROUP by data_id

this query displayng the table now I need to CONCAT names and INNER JOIN with another table.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using -- and MySQL doesn't support `pivot`.  `SUM()` seems very unlikely on columns with those names.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would all help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using conditional aggregation, which I think is:

```
select data_id,
       max(case when name = 'ApplicantsFirstName' then value end) as ApplicantsFirstName,
       max(case when name = 'ApplicantsMiddleName' then value end) as ApplicantsMiddleName,
       max(case when name = 'ApplicantsLastName' then value end) as ApplicantsLastName
from wphl_cf7_data_entry
group by data_id;
```

This will also work in both MySQL and SQL Server (the original database tags).

Comment: I also did this and it worked for that table but I am having problem with CONCAT this newly created columns and inner join it with another table can you please show me how to do it with this code..

Comment: @SjShaggy . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question -- and consider accepting the answer here.